# Ember 2 Routing Subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, dns, ember-cli

I have a Ember 2 application (ember-cli) that uses a Rails API as the back end. For this application, I have enabled Wildcard DNS with my DNS Provider (Cloudflare). When a user signs up with my website, I want them to be able to use their subdomain to access their public home page.

For example:

A user named `Steve` signs up for my site located at `awesome.com`. So Steve browses to `steve.awesome.com`, which internally would translate to `awesome.com/users/steve`. How do I setup my Ember routes such that it can route based off of the subdomain?

Comment: I don't think Ember.js cares about the subdomain Andrew, but you should be able to accomplish the goal you want. I suggest visiting our Slack community to discuss strategies.

Answer (score 0):

I have come to a solution, but it isn't exactly what I was initially looking for. I realized there really isn't a reason why the URL has to be `awesome.com/users/steve`, and instead have decided that their subdomain (or custom domain) will act as their identifier. So let's say Steve browses to `steve.awesome.com`, I will figure out the host via `window.location.hostname`, and use that as a lookup key to pass to my Rails API and retrieve user data.

Not exactly the solution I originally was seeking, but it solves my issue!